# Swift: Pass parameter value to Selector function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass value from addKey function to Selector function (didTapAny function) but couldn't figure how. Below is my code:

```
var keyName: UIButton!
func addKey(var keyTitle: String, var yValue: Float32){
    keyName = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
    keyName.setTitle(keyTitle, forState: .Normal)
    keyName.sizeToFit()
    keyName.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    // Couldn't figure how to pass parameter value to Selector at this line
    // action: Selector("didTapAny:")
    keyName.addTarget(self, action: "didTapAny", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    keyName.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24)
    keyName.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 9)
    keyName.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(keyName)
    var keyNameButtonLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: keyName, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem:view, attribute:.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    var keyNameButtonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: keyName, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: yValue)
    view.addConstraints([keyNameButtonLeftSideConstraint, keyNameButtonBottomConstraint])
}

// want to pass above function's keyTitle to this function
func didTapAny(keyTitle: String){
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    proxy.insertText(keyTitle)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> // want to pass above function's keyTitle to this function
>
> func didTapAny(keyTitle: String){

You cannot pass whatever you wish into a button action method. The method will receive a reference to the button and you can access its `currentTitle` property. It goes more like:

```
func didTapAny(sender: UIButton) {

   // use here sender.currentTitle

}
```

Comment: I altered 2 lines of my codes:

    keyName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didTapAny:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    func didTapAny(sender: UIButton) {
        var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
        proxy.insertText(sender.currentTitle)
    }

It works perfectly.
Thanks for the info of cannot pass whatever I wish to the button action.